# addHandlerFocus 'event_decorator' not found

Tags: r, gwidgets

My package is currently developed using gWidgets2RGtk2. I am trying to make it compatible with gWidgets2tcltk. However, I get this error which I can't figure out:

```
Error in connect_to_toolkit_signal(signal, decorator = decorator, emitter = emitter,  : 
object 'event_decorator' not found
```

A small example which is working using gWidgets2RGtk2 but gives the error using gWidgets2tcltk:

```
require(gWidgets2)
gui_example <- function(){

  # Main window.
  w <- gwindow(title=paste("GUI test"), visible = FALSE, name=title)

  # Main group.
  gv <- ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, use.scrollwindow=FALSE, container = w, expand=TRUE) 

  # Notebook.
  nb <- gnotebook(closebuttons = FALSE, dontCloseThese = NULL, container = gv)


  # Define groups.
  tab_1 <- ggroup(container = nb, label="Tab1")
  tab_2 <- ggroup(container = nb, label="Tab2")
  tab_3 <- ggroup(container = nb, label="Tab3")

  gtext(text="Tab1", expand=TRUE, container = tab_1) 
  gtext(text="Tab2", expand=TRUE, container = tab_2) 
  gtext(text="Tab3", expand=TRUE, container = tab_3) 


  addHandlerChanged(nb, handler = function (h, ...) {

    print("CHANGED...")
    print(if(is.null(h$page.no)) svalue(h$obj) else h$page.no)

    # Get active tab.
    tab <- if(is.null(h$page.no)) svalue(h$obj) else h$page.no
    tabName <- names(nb)[tab]

    print(paste("Active tab:", tab))
    print(paste("Active tab name:", tabName))

  })

  addHandlerFocus(w, handler = function (h, ...) {

    print("FOCUS...")

    # Get active tab.
    tab <- svalue(nb)
    tabName <- names(nb)[tab]

    print(paste("Active tab:", tab))
    print(paste("Active tab name:", tabName))

  })

  # Show GUI and first tab.
  svalue(nb) <- 1
  visible(w) <- TRUE
  focus(w)
  message("Example loaded!")

}
```

How do I avoid this error when using the gWidgets2tcltk package, and maintain compatibility with gWidgets2RGtk2?

Here is my system information:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
gWidgets2_1.0-7
gWidgets2RGtk2_1.0-7
RGtk2_2.20.35
gWidgets2tcltk_1.0-5
```

Comment: Uhh, I could fix the bug. The github site has a fix. If you need a CRAN release, please let me know. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. I was about to report it as an issue, but was not sure it was a bug. No need to release to CRAN just yet as there are more to work with in my code. For example, only three tabs show up in my user interface.Should be more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug fixed on GitHub - see comment by @jverzani